# Ordenar un arraylist por un atributo

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un trabajo. La idea es una empresa que tiene partes de trabajo. Los parte de trabajo tienen una fecha de parte por esta fecha tengo que ordenarlos. Ya he implementado la clase y creado el método, pero no se si esta bien hecho. He leído en internet que debería de hacerlo de otra forma poner después del comparable  y alguna cosa más pero no tengo mucha idea.

```
public class ParteDeTrabajo implements Comparable {

private String nombreCliente;
private LocalDate fechaParte;
private String nombreTrabajador;
private char estado;
private LocalDate fechaReparacion;
private double tiempoReparacion;
private String descripcionArreglo;
private List<Material> materiales;

public String getNombreCliente() {
    return nombreCliente;
}

public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
}

public LocalDate getFechaParte() {
    return fechaParte;
}

public void setFechaParte(LocalDate fechaParte) {
    this.fechaParte = fechaParte;
}

public String getNombreTrabajador() {
    return nombreTrabajador;
}

public void setNombreTrabajador(String nombreTrabajador) {
    this.nombreTrabajador = nombreTrabajador;
}

public char getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(char estado) {
    if (this.estado == 'p' || this.estado == 'r') {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

}

public LocalDate getFechaReparacion() {
    return fechaReparacion;
}

public void setFechaReparacion(LocalDate fechaReparacion) {
    this.fechaReparacion = fechaReparacion;
}

public double getTiempoReparacion() {
    return tiempoReparacion;
}

public void setTiempoReparacion(double tiempoReparacion) {
    if (this.tiempoReparacion >= 0) {
        this.tiempoReparacion = tiempoReparacion;
    }
}

public String getDescripcionArreglo() {
    return descripcionArreglo;
}

public void setDescripcionArreglo(String descripcionArreglo) {
    this.descripcionArreglo = descripcionArreglo;
}

public List<Material> getMateriales() {
    return materiales;
}

public void setMateriales(List<Material> materiales) {
    this.materiales = materiales;
}

public ParteDeTrabajo(String nombreCliente, LocalDate fechaParte, String nombreTrabajador, char estado, LocalDate fechaReparacion, double tiempoReparacion, String descripcionArreglo, List<Material> materiales) {
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    this.fechaParte = fechaParte;
    this.nombreTrabajador = nombreTrabajador;
    setEstado(estado);
    this.fechaReparacion = fechaReparacion;
    setTiempoReparacion(tiempoReparacion);
    this.descripcionArreglo = descripcionArreglo;
    this.materiales = materiales;
}

public ParteDeTrabajo() {
    this.nombreCliente = "";
    this.fechaParte = null;
    this.nombreTrabajador = "";
    this.estado = 'p';
    this.fechaReparacion = null;
    this.tiempoReparacion = 0;
    this.descripcionArreglo = "";
    this.materiales = new ArrayList<Material>();
}

public String aniadirMateriales(Material a) {
    materiales.add(a);
    return "material introducidos";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    ParteDeTrabajo p = (ParteDeTrabajo) o;
    if (this.getFechaParte().isAfter(p.getFechaParte())) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (this.getFechaParte().equals(p.getFechaParte())) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

}

Muchas gracias. La verdad que la web esta un poco pesada y no me deja poner la pregunta porque dice que mi repuesta es mayoritariamente código.

Comment: Hola, creo que podrías subir sólo el código relevante. Por otro lado, ¿cuál es la duda en concreto? ¿hay algún error? Si lo que pides es una opinión, creo que este no es el sitio adecuado. Saludos

Comment: La pregunta es como lo ordeno. cual es el codigo relevante?he hecho el compare to pero nos e como ordenarlo y como ponerlo luego en el main

Comment: Deberías implementar algún algoritmo de ordenación para el arreglo. Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo al QuickShort y al Algoritmo de la burbuja. SI quieres mantener el primer arreglo crea un segundo y pasaselo al main mediante un método.

Comment: ya es echo el comparte to y el metodo burbuja es para Arrays normales no para arraylist que yo sepa (que no se mucho)

Comment: Claro, pero el compareTo solo los esta comparando, no ordenando en sí. Haz un doble for en el main para que si la salida del compareTo te de -1,0 o 1 los intercambie, los deje igual, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ya tiene creado el compare to, en el main solo necesitas poner  Collections.sort( aquí pones el nombre del objeto empresa que es donde has dicho que tienes el arraylist y el get del array a ordenar)

Answer (score 0):

En realidad se ve bien tu código. Lo que puedes hacer para ordenar los es colocar un número de asignación para la empresa, como un ID; éste valor incrementará o disminuirá si se agrega o se elimina un nuevo dato.
Éste ID lo puedes hacer con un

```
ArrayList<Integer> ID=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Lo único que tienes que hacer es conocer el ID para cada nuevo dato y si eliminas uno, puedes recurrir a un ciclo for para conocer el número del ID eliminado y así eliminar esa posición de tus demás datos.